# Handle NotConnectedToInternet error in UrlSession task

Tags: swift, error-handling, urlsession

I want to handle NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet in URLSession datatask. I am installing app to the phone and then turn off wifi to handle  NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet. But error is always returns nil even there is no internet? In terminal "finished with error - code: -1009" message is displaying. But error is nill. And i dont handle event if error is not nill. The code is here:`
        func getData() {

```
    let urlString = "http://142.93.186.88/api/v1/auctions/list/\((selectedMenu?.id)!)"

    guard let url = URL(string: urlString)
        else {return}




  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url){ (data, response, error) in

        guard let data = data else { return }


        do{
            let content = try JSONDecoder().decode(HerracDetailModel1.self, from: data)
            for i in 0..<content.data.count {
                self.detailLists.append(content.data[i])
            }

        }

        catch let jsonError{
            print(jsonError)
        }


        if (error == nil)
        {

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                self.table.reloadData()

            }

        }
        if(error != nil)
        {
        print("There is internet")
        }

        }.resume()

}`
```

Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can downcast error to `URLError` and then if downcasted error code property is equal to `URLError.notConnectedToInternet` you know that this error is connected with no internet connection

```
if (error as! URLError).code == URLError.notConnectedToInternet {
    print("No internet connection")
}
```